# extract zip files silently using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, zip, unzip

I have written the below bat file to extract the zip files. But this is not working when I execute it from Jenkins. I suspect that this is because since its trying to launch the copy UI and service is preventing from doing it as windows services dont allow to work with UIs. Is there a way to edit the below script to do the unzipping silently? If there are any other tools, please provide some example.

```
    @echo off
FOR /D %%p IN ("%CD%\Setups\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q

call mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=http://10.101.15.190:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ -Dartifact=k:update-service:1.0.3 -Ddest=Setups/Services/update-service.jar
call mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=http://10.101.15.190:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ -Dartifact=k:installer-prerequisites:1.0.0 -Ddest=Setups/PreRequisites/installer-prerequisites.zip -Dpackaging=zip
call mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=http://10.101.15.190:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ -Dartifact=k:-apps:1.0.0 -Ddest=Setups/Apps/-apps.zip -Dpackaging=zip
call mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=http://10.101.15.190:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ -Dartifact=k:mosquitto:1.0.0 -Ddest=Setups/mosquitto/mosquitto.zip -Dpackaging=zip
call mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=http://10.101.15.190:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ -Dartifact=k:ble-service:1.0 -Ddest=Setups/Services/ble-service.jar
for /r %%i in ("*.zip") do (
    Call :UnZipFile "%%~dpi" "%%~fi"
    del /S /Q "%%~fi"
)
exit \b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
    setlocal
    set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
    if exist "%vbs%" del /f /q "%vbs%"
     >"%vbs%" echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    >>"%vbs%" echo If NOT fso.FolderExists("%~1") Then
    >>"%vbs%" echo fso.CreateFolder("%~1")
    >>"%vbs%" echo End If
    >>"%vbs%" echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    >>"%vbs%" echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace("%~2").items
    >>"%vbs%" echo objShell.NameSpace("%~1").CopyHere(FilesInZip)
    >>"%vbs%" echo Set fso = Nothing
    >>"%vbs%" echo Set objShell = Nothing
    cscript //nologo "%vbs%"
    if exist "%vbs%" del /f /q "%vbs%"
    endlocal
```

Comment: Please use a command line "unzip" tool. There are many..

Comment: @Jayan although there are plenty of unzip tools that could be used, that doesn't mean that they're always a possibility to be used. The reason batch is used most of the times means it has to be compatible with a lot of different windows computers, which might not all have an "unzip tool"

Answer (score 2):

You should use 7zip tool. After you have installed it, you should use the following command.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "C:\myzipfile.7z" -o"C:\ExtractedFolder" *.* -r -y
```

or parameterize with batch file.

> call "C:\Scripts\mycustombatch.bat" "%WORKSPACE%\myzipfile.7z"
>   "C:\ExtractedFolder"

**mycustombatch.bat**

```
cd "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
7z e %1 -o%2 *.* -r -y
```

7z.exe usage examples:http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use a PowerShell script instead, and use something like this:

```
function UnZip
{
    param([string]$zip, [string]$outpath)

    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}
UnZip "D:\YourFile.zip" "D:\The_Path_You_Want_It_To_Be_Extracted"
```

This way you don't require any 3rd party tool to be installed on the build server.